# sequelize association explanation on docs

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js

while reading sequelize doc association part, explanation below really confuses me

> hasOne and belongsTo insert the association key in different models
>   from each other. hasOne inserts the association key in target model
>   whereas belongsTo inserts the association key in the source model.

and also,

```
Player.belongsTo(Team); // Will add a teamId attribute to Player to hold the primary key value for Team
```

it seems that if I set relation between two models, sequelize automatically adds foreign key to the target model.

but according to the article,
https://lorenstewart.me/2016/09/12/sequelize-table-associations-joins/z

we have to manually add foreign key to the model file.

which one is right..?

it has been a while since I questioned about this issue.

Any detailed explanation would really be appreciated.

Any recommended articles about sequelize association to read would also be appreciated since sequelize doc seems not that kind for ORM beginners.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570497/3461055

Comment: @ArifKhan thanks for your comment, but that is totally different question from what I am asking. I am questioning about whether that relation statement adds foreign key automatically or not. this is the issue about whether we have to manually add foreign key to the target model or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it depends on how are you creating your tables. Via `sync` or via `migrations`.

For example

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const Address = sequelize.define('add', {
  address: Sequelize.STRING,
});

User.hasOne(Address);

sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => User.create({
    username: 'test'
  }))
  .then(item => {
    console.log(item.dataValues.itemPrice);
  });
```

This will create a userId field in the database

[image: database screenshot]

Note that I am use `sync`. However if you are using migrations, you would have to create this on your own.

PS: Its better to use `migrations` instead of `sync`.

Comment: thanks for your help. so I have two more question if its okay for you.

first of all, 
when using migration, we create model with sequelize-cli, and 2 files are created (model file, and migration file)
so at that case, do we have to manually add foreign-key to the migration file, not the model file right..?

Comment: secondly, there is no migration file on sync, because of course sync it self has nothing to do with migration. when it comes to using sync, all I have to do is caring with model file. but on the other hand the case of migration, which is the basic difference between migration and model file..? sync only manages model file, but migration manages both model and migration file.. so I am confused

Comment: sorry for bothering with this basic questions, but I really couldn`t solve my ambuiguity with the articles presented on google..

Comment: I know the difference between sync and migration. but do now know exactly what the differences between the operations and role of migration file and model file are.

Comment: hi @jwkoo happy to help! 
For first Q: Correct. Foreign key has to be specified manually. For second Q and last Q: Migration file manages database schema and nothing else. Model has to be manually updated everytime you change you schema via migration. Ex: You want to add a new column to an existing table: If you are using a migration, you write a new migration and then update the model. If you are using sync, the only option you have is to use `{force: true}` in sync This means that existing table and its data would be dropped as well. As you can see this is not desirable in production code.

Comment: For future references, its better to ask a new question as it would help other fellow developers who would face the same question.

Comment: Thanks all for your help I appreciate that!