# express what is model file actually doing compared to migration files?

Tags: mysql, migration, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize-cli migration when it comes to dealing with mysql db.

If I type the command

```
sequelize init
```

two folders are created `models` and `migrations`

also, if I set associations between two models, for example

```
User.hasMany(Posts)
```

I have to manually add foreign keys to the migration file.

(but not to the model file, right?)

also, there are columns in migration file such as created_at, updated_at

but not in the model file.

When it comes to use `db.sync();` there are no such migration files, so I don`t have to manually foreign keys  to the model file.

I understand that migration files are only concerning with the db table schema, but then what is model file actually doing..?

Does that model file have nothing to do with db table?

I understand what the differences between sync and migration, (sync drop all the tables, if force:true is to be set but not the migration)

but maybe I failed to understand what is internally going on (model between migration)

any advice would really be appreciated !

Comment: @AbhinavD could you please help me finding out solutions?

Comment: Looks like this did not came up as a notification to me. Let me know if I can still help with this

Answer (score 2):

When you use sequelize-cli the createdAt and updatedAt columns are already created for you as sequelize uses them to update the table. You can disable them.

The sequelize model file doesnt need createdAt and updatedAt to define the changes as they are done by the sequelize.

You will have to manually add foreign key to both migration file and model.
Model file is the reference for your sequelize to interact with your database schema.

It sets the parameter for your sequelize to trigger the query to your database.
You can say migration file is concerned with your database schema and model file is concerned about what data is being stored in your db.

Example consider user table and its basicinfo.

User Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Users = sequelize.define('users', {
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
   }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    Users.hasOne(models.basicinfo, {
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      as: 'BasicInfo'
    });
};
  return Users;
};
```

Basic info Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var basicinfo = sequelize.define('basicinfo', {
    first_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    last_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
};{});
  basicinfo.associate = function (models) {
    basicinfo.belongsTo(models.users, {
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    });
  };
  return basicinfo;
};
```

Hope this clears your confusion little you will learn more as you use this great library.

Here's my updated answer with migration files for each model.

**user-migration**

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
  });
 },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  }
};
```

**basicinfo-migration**

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('basicinfo', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: 'users',
          key: 'user_id',
          as: 'user_id'
        }
      },
      profile_img: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      first_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      last_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('basicinfo');
  }
};
```

Comment: really appreciate for your detailed-explanation. One thing I am still wondering is that sequelize docs says if I set association between two models, sequelize automatically creates foreign key. As I questioned before 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50386288/sequelize-association-explanation-on-docs/50387602?noredirect=1#comment87793903_50387602

we only have to create foreignkey manually to the migration file.

Comment: Is that "You will have to manually add foreign key to both migration file and model. "  meaning also same with that? which one is right..?

Comment: You will have to add columns in your migration file, currently i am out once i reach home will the migration file for my example so you can clear some of your doubt