# sequelize model, migration file and foreign key. which one is right?

Tags: node.js, express, model, sequelize.js

At first time when I started studying sequelize I just had no idea, just copy and pasted the code when it comes to make relations between two models.

It really confused me whether I have to insert foreign keys both to the model file and migration file or for only migration file.

I knew that the migrations are files that have commands for changing your database.

so definitely we have to manually insert foreign keys to the migration file so that database can create them.

In sequelize doc, if we add relations like has many and belongs to, the sequelize will automatically add foreign keys.

so I was really confused whether I have to add them or not.

some questions I asked before the answers were fifty-fifty.

some says that we don`t have to manually add foreign keys to the model because sequelize will automatically add them.

but some says that we have to manually add foreign keys to the model because we have to match(sync) columns between models and migration files.

even worse, the articles explaining about sequelize relations are differ from each other.

so, which one is right??

I really want to get clear answer.

It will be really thankful to get some reasons (if we have to add foreign key to the model)

not exaggerated, I have been curious of this issue for about six month.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While create the migration you should write the foreign keys also. Also write it in the models, So it will be easy to handle the queries.
We can see it with example. Consider their are two table Item And Item_Types

1 Item_type has many Items so,

Migration File for Item_type  (migration_create_item_type.js)

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('item_types', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        item_type: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        type_desc: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        createdAt: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
        },
        updatedAt: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
        }
    });
},
down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('item_types');
}
};
```

Migration file for item (migration_create_item.js)

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('items', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        item_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        item_desc: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        item_type_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: 'item_types',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        createdAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
        },
        updatedAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
        }
    });
},
down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('items');
}
};
```

**Please note that always create the Parent table 1st then others i.e. create all the tables that doen't have a foreign key and then others**

Model file the Item_type (item_type.js)

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
var item_type = sequelize.define('item_type', {
    item_type: DataTypes.STRING,
    type_desc: DataTypes.STRING
});
item_type.associate = function (models) {
    item_type.hasMany(models.item, {foreignKey: 'item_type_id'});
};
return item_type;
};
```

Model File the item (item.js)

```
'use strict';
 var Logger = require('./../utils/logger');

 var log = new Logger('item_type_factory');
 module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
 var item = sequelize.define('item', {
    item_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    item_desc: DataTypes.STRING
 });
 item.associate = function (models) {
    item.item_type = item.belongsTo(models.item_type, {foreignKey: 'id', target_key: 'item_type_id'});
    item.order_details = item.hasMany(models.order_details);
    item.user = item.belongsToMany(models.user, {through: 'supplier_items'})
};

item.addNewItem = function (data) {
    return item.create(data, {include: [{association: item.item_type}]});
};

item.findAndCreate = function (data, item_name) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        item.findOrCreate({
            where: {'item_name': item_name}, defaults: data
        }).spread(function (record_data, created) {
            resolve(record_data);
        }).catch(function (insert_error) {
            reject(insert_error);
        });
    });
};

item.findAllItems = function () {
    return item.findAll({
        include: [{association: item.item_type}]
    });
};
return item;
};
```

For sequlize basics you can refer the following article,
[Getting started with Sequelize](https://medium.com/@akshay.gadhave/getting-started-with-sequelize-cf160fc76ba) For the basics only.

Comment: this is really great. appreciate for your detailed explanation with code.

still one thing I am wondering is that, according to the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50386288/sequelize-association-explanation-on-docs even if we don`t add any foreign keys, the db creates foreign key column. ( the case of sync )

Comment: so if we don`t add foreign key to the model, there is no way to access them.. right?

Comment: if we maually add foreign key to the migration file, the db will create them. but if we don`t add foreign keys to the model, there is no way to access and manipulate with them. Am I understand correctly?

Comment: so it is not necessary to write foreign key options to the model. (regards to the db itself). but as we have to access and use that relationships, we have to add foreign keys to the model. I am just re-asking to assure if I am understanding this issue correctly ! thanks ! @Akshay Gadhave

Comment: If you see the model code that associate function will manage the relationship. While you run the migrations using db.migrate(). It will run it sequentially as per the time. That is why we create the master table 1st.

Comment: Migrations are basically design to migrate right, So why we add the foreign keys and manage relation ship manually !!. Handle it through the Migrations scripts.

Comment: sorry for bothering with my lack of understanding.. to rephrase, 

        item_type_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: 'item_types',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },

this code for migration file is for ONLY db, and db itself will have relation. contrastly, hasmany, belongsto and foreign key option added to the model file is just for using(querying) that db which has relation already, with js grammar ( not with the raw query). (not managing db. db is managed by migration file).

Comment: If we don`t add foreign keys to the model, there is no way to access(use) that db. (access mean for orm usage not the db itself for model create.) @Akshay Gadhave

Comment: Yes you are right. Migrations and model are the two different things, Migrations might be for alter table, Insert default values. That should not be related to the model. As per the definition Model is the updated version of your database table.!!

Comment: Yes if we don't add the foreign key we can not write the correct query through the orm.

Comment: Basically while use migration the db contains 1 additional table "SequelizeMeta" That contains the migration name that execute properly. You can also downgrade the migrations using migration queries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172014/discussion-between-akshay-gadhave-and-jwkoo).

Answer (score 4):

## How should we create DB schema

We have two options here. Migrations or Sequelize using `sync`. Always prefer migrations over `sync`. Migrations are more powerful, you can undo, redo and much more with it. `sync` does not reflect table alterations. For example, you define a certain model say `User` and forgot to add `gender`. Now if you want to add this column with Sequelize, you would have to use `force:true` which would drop all of your `User` data which is not desirable in production.

## Who should define the foreign key constraints

From software design principles, your database constraints and validations should always be in place irrespective whether application logic (Sequelize) implements the same logic or not. For example, a new developer can write a raw query and can mess up your whole database if you do not have the right constraints.

However we also want to use sequelize to make the right queries with all the associations. The only way sequelize can do this if it knows what associations exists in the db and what should be the foreign key.

So, foreign key constrains should be defined at both migration as well as sequelize level.

## Example of db constraints

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the constraints are defined on my database schema.

## Example of sequelize constraints

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Designation = sequelize.define('designation', {
    doctorId: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'doctor_id',
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {});
  Designation.associate = (models) => {
    models.designation.belongsTo(models.doctor, {
      onDelete: 'cascade',
    });
  };
```

Comment: appreciate for your answer. so purpose of adding foreign keys to the model is to control database with non-query (js grammer). am I understood correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50386288/sequelize-association-explanation-on-docs according to this article, if I use sync and foreign key columns are automatically created to the db even if I don`t add the foreign key to the model. But even if we use sync, it is recommended to add foreign keys to the model since we have to control the db, right?

Comment: my confusion will fully be cleared if above those two questions are correct. thank you! @AbhinavD

Comment: To the first comment: Yes. Sequelize is an ORM and we can use all its power so that our querying becomes easier and so many other benefits sequelize comes with.  For comment 2: If you have defined associations, sequelize will try to assume the foreign key name and use that to do associations.

Comment: now I solved my curiosity. so either using sync or migration,  inserting foreign key to the model is just an option. but if we want to querying with orm, we have to. so that optional thing might be necessary. thank you so much.