# (Sequelize) hasOne association is not creating foreign key

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, associations, has-one

I've created two model as follows

**UserModel**

```
const UserModel = database.define("user", {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notNull: {
                msg: "name is required"
            },
            notEmpty: {
                msg: "name cannot be empty"
            }
        }
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: {
                msg: "invalid email provided"
            },
            notNull: {
                msg: "email is required"
            },
            notEmpty: {
                msg: "email cannot be empty"
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notNull: {
                msg: "password is required"
            },
            notEmpty: {
                msg: "password cannot be empty"
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**UserType**

```
const UserType = database.define("userType", {
    name: {
        type : Sequelize.STRING(30),
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            notNull: {
                msg: "name is required"
            },
            notEmpty: {
                msg: "name cannot be empty"
            }
        }
    }
})
```

My required association is as follows

1. Every `UserModel` should have one status. 
   I'm using `sqlite` as dialect.

To achieve that i code like following

```
UserModel.hasOne(UserType, { foreignKey: { allowNull : false }, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
```

for this generated `SQL` is following

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, `email` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);

I've seen declaring association in both ways like following

```
UserModel.hasOne(UserType, { foreignKey: { allowNull : false }, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
UserType.hasMany(UserModel, { foreignKey: { allowNull : false }, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
```

In that case the `SQL` is generated as follows

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, `lastName` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, `email` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `userTypeId` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `userTypes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);

Even if i put only the line, the foreign key is created in `SQL`

```
UserType.hasMany(UserModel, { foreignKey: { allowNull : false }, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
```

I've read  [hasOne doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/has-one.js~HasOne.html) / [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2031). In the github issue it says that the doc should be updated (@2014). So what is current `hasOne` association doing ?

Another thing, i know two way association is required to get related models [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50198893/2143128) , but i don't need the reverse way association like fetching all the `user` given their `status`, thats why i'm only declaring one way association.